# HtAccess rewriting, removing a part of the text between the first two slashes and adding index.php after it

Tags: .htaccess

I got the following url:

> 127.0.0.1/abc_123456/default/index/index/

Which should be rewritten to:

> 127.0.0.1/123456/index.php/default/index/index/

So remove abc_ and add index.php after it. Problem is that the digits are variable, but the abc_ isn't.

I had the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /abc_

RewriteRule ^abc_(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/index.php/$2
```

But that resulted in the url being rewritten to:

> 127.0.0.1/123456/default/index/index.php/index/

Seems like I'm almost there, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this simple rule:

```
RewriteRule ^abc_([0-9]+)/(.*)$ $1/index.php/$2 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /abc_([0-9]+)/([^\ \?]+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/index.php/%2 [L]
```

**EDIT**

> However, you are right about the other rule, that's the one giving the error; RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\ /abc_ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 That one is used to rewrite if the page does not contain the /abc_123456/

Add an extra condition to that rule as below

```
#if not abc_
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\ /abc_  [NC]
#if not already index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Gives me an internal server error. The condition seems alright, but the rule isn't.

Comment: @user1194648 If you comment out the rules above, do you get an error if you access `127.0.0.1/123456/index.php/default/index/index/` directly. Do you have any other rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: Requesting the url directly gives me the page as expected. However, you are right about the other rule, that's the one giving the error;                                                           RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\ /abc_
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1                                               That one is used to rewrite if the page does not contain the /abc_123456/

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Your solution works too, though the above [anubhava] has my preferation as it is more neat.

Answer (score 0):

for example, if you need similar solution, when visited this url:

```
http://yoursite.com/subpage1/subpage2/?YOURSTRING=blabla
```

to redirected visitor to

```
http://yoursite.com/subpage1/subpage2/
```

then see link - `http://stackoverflow.com/a/15680832/2215124`