# 301 Redirect URL with Question Mark/Parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect a URL with a question mark, but it's not really classed as a parameter. I'm just not sure what query_string I would use if doing a mod_rewrite.

I would like to redirect:

> /category/Product-Name?.html

To:

> /category/Product-Name.html

Notice the only difference is the removal of the question mark.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Found following thread which seems to be the closest to the problem above but still no luck - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165287/removing-trailing-question-mark-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\.html)$
RewriteRule ^(category/Product-Name)$ $1%1? [L]
```